# C# Serialize Dictionary JSON

Tags: javascript, c#, json

I am trying to serialize a dictionary in C# using JSON.NET and then consume it in a web application. This is the format I am returned but am unable to use it as I do not think it is in the correct format. I have tried the following:

Dictionary Serialization:

```
    [JsonExtensionData]
    public static Dictionary<string, object> objectDictionary = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    string parametersJSON = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objectDictionary, Formatting.Indented);

var x = get.getData;
x.p11.Name

{
  "p11": {
  "Name": "Parameter 1",
  "Value": "1.00",
  "Unit": "m",
  "MinValue": "0.00",
  "MaxValue": "5.00",
  "Number": 11,
  "DefaultValue": "0.00"
},
  "p546": {
  "Name": "Parameter 2",
  "Value": "0.0000",
  "Unit": "Hz",
  "MinValue": "-480.000",
  "MaxValue": "480.000",
  "Number": 546,
  "DefaultValue": "0.0000"
},
  "p7": {
  "Name": "Parameter 3",
  "Value": "0.00",
  "Unit": "Amps",
  "MinValue": "0.00",
  "MaxValue": "44.00",
  "Number": 7,
  "DefaultValue": "0.00"
}}
```

Comment: Would you please edit your question and show us how you're attempting to serialize a Dictionary.

Comment: What do you mean *as I do not think it is in the correct format*. What format are you expecting?

Comment: I am expecting JSON

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]Nothing is wrong with your data:

```
var x = JSON.parse(jsonstr);
var name = x["p11"].Name;
```

For more information:
A Dictionary is parsed into an associative array (http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp)

Comment: when I try parsing again I get Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>). I used JSON.parse in my service. What I provided was after JSON.parse.

Comment: When I try without parsing again, I get Cannot read property 'Name' of undefined. When I just display what the call returns I get what is in the original question.

Comment: the jsonstring is correct, so check if get.getData does return undefined.

Comment: when I just display x, I see the data above. So I know it is returning something.

Comment: hm try to change your dictionary from <string, object> to <string, dynamic>

Comment: I tried that, same result... I see that you have it working. Very strange.

Comment: Sorry it was an issue with my gui being created before the call created. It is working. Thank you.